# Plupload, Carrierwave & Rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, plupload

1:

I'm looking for a step by step tutorial for Plupload (or another multifile upload) + Carrierwave on Rails 3.2.
I found it : http://neovintage.blogspot.fr/2010/06/file-uploads-with-rails-3-plupload-and.html

But I always get 'Error 200'.

2:

If I can make work Carrierwave + Plupload (or anoter), I want to know if it's possible to let the user chose the thumbnail?

3:

And to finish, is it possible to add a gaussian blur to the photo, like the cropping image system (Select the area, and then, add the blur)

Answer (score 1):

I'd checkout the plupload rails gem and the carrierwave railscasts.Here is a link to how I set plupload up with carrierwave for multiple file uploads: [How can I create multiple objects in a single form in Rails 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298325/how-can-i-create-multiple-objects-in-a-single-form-in-rails-3-1)

Not sure about the other two